# Getting black screen on creating Triangle using OpeGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm making an sample OpenGL ES android app referring android developers website.
I'm trying to draw a triangle.
I have done every thing as they said in that but I end up with the black screen.
please help me solving this problem.

I have written all the classes as inner classes of main activity.

here is main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GLSurfaceView surfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    surfaceView=new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(surfaceView);
}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView{

    MyGLRenderer myGLRenderer;
    Triangle triangle;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        //initialiging triangle
        triangle=new Triangle();

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        myGLRenderer=new MyGLRenderer();

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(myGLRenderer);

    }
}

static class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
    Triangle triangle=new Triangle();

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,3.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int i, int i1) {
        //redraw color backgroung
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, 10, 10);
        triangle.draw();
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader,shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }
}


//triangle class
static class Triangle{
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    int mprogram;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    static final int cordinates=3;
    float triangle_coordinates[]={
            0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f, // top
            -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f, // bottom left
            0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f  // bottom right
    };

    private final int vertexCount=triangle_coordinates.length/cordinates;
    private final int vertexStride=cordinates*4;

    public void draw(){
        // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mprogram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mprogram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        //prepare triangle coordinates data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle,cordinates,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,vertexStride,vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mprogram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
    String vertexShadeColor="attribute vec4 vPosition;"+"void main(){gl_Position=vPosition;}";
    String fragmentShadeColor="precision mediump float; uniform vec4 vColor;"+"void main(){gl_FragColor=vColor;}";

    // Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };

    public Triangle(){

        int vertexShader=MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,vertexShadeColor);
        int fragmentShader=MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,fragmentShadeColor);

        // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        mprogram=GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        //add vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mprogram,vertexShader);

        //add fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mprogram,fragmentShader);

        // creates OpenGL ES program executables
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mprogram);

        ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangle_coordinates.length*4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();

        vertexBuffer.put(triangle_coordinates);

        vertexBuffer.position(0);
    }
}
}
```

any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your onDrawFrame method MyGLRenderer class, you should clear the background and you don't have to use glViewport. You should initialize Triangle class in MyGLRenderer in onSurfaceCreated, So your MyGLRenderer class will look like this

```
static class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
        Triangle triangle;

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
            // Set the background frame color
            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,3.0f);
            triangle=new Triangle();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int i, int i1) {
            //redraw color backgroung
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//            GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, 10, 10);
            triangle.draw();
        }

        public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
            // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
            // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

            // add the source code to the shader and compile it
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader,shaderCode);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

            return shader;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SriDattaYalla I updated the answer, you have to do some modification as well. See the updated answer. You can remove Triangle object creation in MyGLSurfaceView class. It is of no use.

Comment: @SriDattaYalla let me know if its working or not? Thanks

Comment: Happy coding @SriDatta